# What is the equivalent of regularization in optimization theory?

Tags: optimization, regularization

I'm using a coordinate search to find an optima in a noisy search space. I'm wondering whether there's a notion of regularization in optimization to help mitigate avoid the noise? Regularization seems to be a topic exclusive to machine learning.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: It's not.  If you've studied any optimization theory, there is a duality between constrained optimization problems and unconstrained problems.  In this context the constrained problem is called "primal" and the unconstrained is called "dual".  The duality gives a way of passing between the domains.  When this is done, the constraints in the primal problem turn up as penalties in the dual problem, just like in regularization.  I'm not sure this is applicable to your case, but these ideas are worth having seen.

Comment: Here's a wiki on the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)

Comment: If you want to minimize a noisy objective function, the thing to look into is 'stochastic optimization' (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226554/minimizing-approximate-function)). Some techniques that can be used for stochastic optimization can incorporate regularization (e.g. Bayesian optimization, which involves fitting an approximation to the noisy function).

Answer (score 2):

Answer  copied from comments by Matthew Drury:  It's not. If you've studied any optimization theory, there is a duality between constrained optimization problems and unconstrained problems. In this context the constrained problem is called "primal" and the unconstrained is called "dual". The duality gives a way of passing between the domains. When this is done, the constraints in the primal problem turn up as penalties in the dual problem, just like in regularization. I'm not sure this is applicable to your case, but these ideas are worth having seen.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)